# XML Import Warning: Informatica

Tags: metadata, informatica, xml-import

I am getting the following warning message while I tried to import XML file in Informatica repository.

> Warning: Unexpected condition at: Wcursor.cpp: 305
>
> Contact Informatica technical support for assistance
>
> Continuing may result in damage to your repository.

[image]

The XML file is around 70mb and has got around 4500 objects in it. I am migrating an entire application from one server to another.
Not sure why this issue happens. I tried several times and from other client system as well, but no luck.

For importing the XML via command line using "pmrep" command, we need control file. But I dont have any control file for this XML. So cant go with that option.

It would be great if somebody can help me sort out this issue.

Details:

Infa version 9.1
Mounted on Unix environment.

Comment: It might be a insufficient memory issue (only a guess). Can you try exporting a smaller number of objects and try importing that?

Comment: @Samik-- you mean to say...from the same 70mb XML file....first import source/target objects..then mappings..then sessions...and so on......?????  ...OR.... while exporting itself split them into different files?????????

Comment: I meant selecting a fewer number of objects while exporting. You can export say 50 workflows at a time from repository manager. Dependent objects will be included automatically in the export file.

Comment: @Samik --  ok..let me check..thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same problem back some time ago. XML parsing takes a lot of memory and / or GUI can't handle it. My solution was to use pmrep command line tool. Worked for me - my workflow was composed of around 3600 objects afair.

If you don't have a control file - create one! Here's a very simple template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE IMPORTPARAMS SYSTEM "impcntl.dtd">
<!--IMPORTPARAMS This inputs the options and inputs required for import operation -->
<!--CHECKIN_AFTER_IMPORT Check in objects on successful import operation -->
<!--CHECKIN_COMMENTS Check in comments -->
<!--APPLY_LABEL_NAME Apply the given label name on imported objects -->
<!--RETAIN_GENERATED_VALUE Retain existing sequence generator, normalizer and XML DSQ current values in the destination -->
<!--COPY_SAP_PROGRAM Copy SAP program information into the target repository -->
<!--APPLY_DEFAULT_CONNECTION Apply the default connection when a connection used by a session does not exist in the target repository -->
<IMPORTPARAMS CHECKIN_AFTER_IMPORT="YES" CHECKIN_COMMENTS="PMREP_IMPORT_TEST" RETAIN_GENERATED_VALUE="NO" COPY_SAP_PROGRAM="NO" APPLY_DEFAULT_CONNECTION="NO">
<!--FOLDERMAP matches the folders in the imported file with the folders in the target repository -->
<FOLDERMAP SOURCEFOLDERNAME="YOUR FIRST SOURCE FOLDER NAME" SOURCEREPOSITORYNAME="REP_DEV" TARGETFOLDERNAME="YOUR FIRST SOURCE FOLDER NAME" TARGETREPOSITORYNAME="REP_TEST"/>
<FOLDERMAP SOURCEFOLDERNAME="YOUR SECOND TARGET FOLDER NAME" SOURCEREPOSITORYNAME="REP_DEV" TARGETFOLDERNAME="YOUR SECOND TARGET FOLDER NAME" TARGETREPOSITORYNAME="REP_TEST"/>
<!--Import will only import the objects in the selected types in TYPEFILTER node -->
<!--TYPENAME type name to import. This should comforming to the element name in powermart.dtd, e.g. SOURCE, TARGET and etc.-->
<!--RESOLVECONFLICT allows to specify resolution for conflicting objects during import. The combination of specified child nodes can be supplied -->
<RESOLVECONFLICT>
<!--TYPEOBJECT allows objects of certain type to apply replace/reuse upon conflict-->
<!--TYPEOBJECT = ALL conflict resolution for ALL types of objects -->
<TYPEOBJECT OBJECTTYPENAME="ALL" RESOLUTION="REPLACE"/>
<!--SPECIFICOBJECT allows a particular object(name, typename etc.) to apply replace/reuse upon conflict -->
<!--NAME Object name-->
<!--EXTRANAME Source DBD name - required for source object to identify uniquely-->
<!--OBJECTTYPENAME Object type name-->
<!--FOLDERNAME Folder which the object belongs to-->
<!--REPOSITORYNAME Repository name that this object belongs to-->
<!--RESOLUTION Resolution to apply for the object in case of conflict-->
<!--SPECIFICOBJECT NAME="your_object" OBJECTTYPENAME="your_object_type" FOLDERNAME="your_source_folder" REPOSITORYNAME="your_source_repo" RESOLUTION="REPLACE"/-->
</RESOLVECONFLICT>
</IMPORTPARAMS>
```

Comment: I dont have the control file to do the PMREP command. Is there any workaround for this ?

Comment: Thanks... What should be the file extension? XML or CNF or DTD ?

Comment: I've been using .XML - but it's possible that any will work fine as long as the content is as expected.